# Query with AS with aliaces with spaces in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

i have this challenge on tree house

We're back in our e-commerce database. 
There's a products table with the columns id, name, description and price.
Can you retrieve both the name and description aliased as "Product Name" and "Product Description".

And my code is

```
SELECT name  AS 'Product Name' , description  AS ' Product Description' FROM  products;
```

But is says an error..

Can you please tell me where i am doing it wrong? thanks

The columns you selected were named Product Name, Product Description and not 'Product Name' and 'Product Description'.
[image]

Comment: The query seems OK. What is the error you are getting?

Comment: @marc - you have a **space** before `Product Description` as your alias

Comment: Can you share the error message that you are getting?

Comment: @KobyDouek Added Picture..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the exercise you posted says, the column alias names must be without `'`. Since the aliases have spaces in them, you would need to enclose the names with `[]`, not with `'`.

Try this:

```
SELECT name AS [Product Name], description AS [Product Description] FROM  products;
```

Comment: In Mysql, you need to use backtick `

Comment: @Koby Thanks It Worked

Comment: @MarcAndreJiacarrini Happy to help. Good luck with your projects / studies!

Answer (score 0):

It seems the task 1 is waiting for double quotes but you're using single quotes.

Anyway, you can use single quotes, it's correct.

Answer (score -1):

SQL identifiers must be in backticks when using MySQL. You put single quotes around the column names.

And by the way: You have an extra space in ' Product Desciption'

Comment: Sorry, it is backtracks in mysql. Updated my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Backticks work well for Mysql. Try this

```
SELECT name  AS `Product Name` , description  AS `Product Description` FROM  products;
```